# HttpResponseMessage Content Property in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, compact-framework

I am building a .NET 4.5 MVC 4 Web API that will have publicly exposed Controller Methods that I wish to secure access to.  I have created a Action Filter Attribute to check for a properly encoded RSA token shown below gutted for brevity:

```
    public class TokenValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            //authorize user
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized User")
            };                
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my .NET 3.5 CF application I would do the following:

```
public static List<string> GetAvailableProjectIds()
        {
        var idList = new List<string>();
        var url = "the url";
        var req = CreateRequest(url, true);

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                //do something with the resonse
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return idList;
    }
```

The Exception that is caught is a WebException and contains the correct 403 Forbiden Status Code.  But nothing more helpful that I can find.

Is there a way to get at the Content property so I can display to the end user that they tried authenticating with an "Unauthorized User"?

Comment: you mean there is no body with "Unauthorized User" content in it? also if why not send back "Unauthorized" status code instead for this scenario?

Comment: no, while looking through the WebException in debug mode, I don't see "Unauthorized User" anywhere.  Point taken on using an "Unauthorized" status code.  That would be more meaningful than "Forbiden".  However, there are plenty of scenarios where the status codes just won't be informative enough.  Maybe you're querying a Web Service that tells you what time your favorite sports team plays tonight.  Wouldn't you rather get back a message that says, "Sorry your team isn't playing tonight", instead of "NotFound" response?  "NotFound" gets the point across, but isn't nearly as friendly.

Comment: Sure, having a message is definitely useful...just to be sure, could you check through Fiddler what kind of response is the service returning just to eliminate any problem with the service

Comment: the service is definitely returning the message.  For example, if i try and navigate to http://url/api/GetSomething, i'll see a response in the browser window of "Requests must be made via HTTPS".  Just can't figure out how to find that in the WebException that is caught in the CF app.

Answer (score 0):

I never really liked that behavior, that it uses exceptions when the communication was just fine.  Try adding this extension method:

```
private static HttpResponse GetAnyResponse(this HttpRequest req)
{
   HttpResponse retVal = null;

   try
   {
      retVal = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()
   }
   catch (WebException webEx)
   {
      retVal = webEx.Response;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // these are the "bad" exceptions, let them pass
      throw;
   }

   return webEx;   
}
```

And then change your code to this:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetAnyResponse())
{
    //do something with the resonse
}
```

Comment: And obviously once you have the Response object you can access the headers, body, etc...